# Apache httpd cant write to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/

Tags: linux, apache, cgi, selinux

Im trying to use a script ,thats started by apache through the server, to change the ifcfg-eth0 file in network-scripts.

I have SELinux disabled so thats not the issue. Also I changed the whole /etc/ group and user to apache, yet it still did not work.

The script does work if I put the file in /var/www/cgi-bin.

I also get a permission denied error in the apache log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't bring myself to help you make Apache write to files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`. But there is another option: create a symlink from `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` to a file that Apache can write to, for example:

```
mv /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.bak
ln -s /var/www/cgi-bin/ifcfg-eth0 /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

This way, your (ahem, dangerous) CGI script can rewrite the file in `/var/www/cgi-bin`, and the system can get the network settings from it.